# MySQL Problem with large numbers

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to put together a function to convert a size from one type to another (e.g. bytes >> gigabytes).

An extract is below

```
DROP FUNCTION fc_convSize;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `fc_convSize`(inVal BIGINT) 
RETURNS DECIMAL(25,2)
NO SQL
BEGIN
    -- bytes 2 exabytes 
    SET @inVal := inVal/1024/1024/1024/1024/1024/1024;
    RETURN @outVal;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But it doesn't work with large numbers. e.g.

```
mysql> SET @input1 := (SELECT @@global.max_binlog_cache_size);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT fc_convSize(@input1);
ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'inVal' at row 1
```

But from what I can tell, max_binlog_cache_size is `184467440737095*47520*` and the maximum for a BIGINT is `184467440737095*51615*` so it should fit, right?

But it gets stranger.

```
mysql> SET @input1 := (SELECT @@global.max_binlog_cache_size);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @input1/1024/1024/1024/1024/1024/1024;
+---------------------------------------+
| @input1/1024/1024/1024/1024/1024/1024 |
+---------------------------------------+
|           -0.000000000000003552713679 |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec) 


mysql> SET @input2 := (18446744073709547520);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @input2/1024/1024/1024/1024/1024/1024;
+---------------------------------------+
| @input2/1024/1024/1024/1024/1024/1024 |
+---------------------------------------+
|           -0.000000000000003552713679 |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT 18446744073709547520/1024/1024/1024/1024/1024/1024;
+----------------------------------------------------+
| 18446744073709547520/1024/1024/1024/1024/1024/1024 |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                        15.999999999999996447286321 |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What's going on???

Answer (score 2):

> But from what I can tell, max_binlog_cache_size is
>   184467440737095*47520* and the maximum for a BIGINT is
>   184467440737095*51615* so it should fit, right?

The maximum value of BIGINT **SIGNED** is 9223372036854775807.
The maximum value of BIGINT **UNSIGNED** is 18446744073709551615.
SIGNED is the default behavior. Hence the **ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value error.**

In the subsequent examples, you are expecting the @input1 variable to act like a BIGINT. But in MySQL, the datatype of a session variable depends on the value that is being assigned at runtime. For example:

```
rds@int[(none)]> set @i := 9223372036854775807;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

rds@int[(none)]> select @i + 0.0;
+-----------------------+
| @i + 0.0              |
+-----------------------+
| 9223372036854775807.0 |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In the above example, the variable *@input1* is acting like a BIGINT.
But if we increase the value of @input1 by 1(**beyond the range of **BIGINT SIGNED****) the behavior changes.

```
rds@int[(none)]> set @i := 9223372036854775808;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

rds@int[(none)]> select @i + 0.0;
+------------------------+
| @i + 0.0               |
+------------------------+
| -9223372036854775808.0 |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I think that in this case the session variable is acting like a **FLOAT**.

As suggested by Rick James, CAST the variable to the desired datatype to avoid such an unpredictable situation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to declare the argument as a bigint?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fc_convSize(inVal decimal(40,0))
RETURNS DECIMAL(25,2) 
NO SQL 
BEGIN 
    return inVal/1024/1024/1024/1024/1024/1024; 
END$$

select fc_convSize(18446744073709547520000000123333232323);
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| fc_convSize(18446744073709547520000000123333232323) |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                             15999999999999996447.29 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

However:

```
select fc_convSize(10000*18446744073709547520);
ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(10000 * 18446744073709547520)'
```

MySQL tries to fit the result of the multiplication in a bigint which fails. You can cast one of the arguments to void this:

```
select fc_convSize(10000*cast(18446744073709547520 as decimal(40,0)));
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| fc_convSize(10000*cast(18446744073709547520 as decimal(40,0))) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                      160000.00 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Note that I just grabbed decimal(40,0) out of thin air, just pick something that is large enough for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Bytes to gigabytes on only 3 divides:

```
/1024/1024/1024
```

A simpler (and faster) way to do this

```
SET @input1 := (SELECT @@global.max_binlog_cache_size);
```

is

```
SELECT @input1 := @@global.max_binlog_cache_size;
```

The problem with `SET @input2 := (18446744073709547520);` is that the number is bigger than can fit in a `BIGINT SIGNED`.  So it (somewhat erroneously) stores the 64 bits blindly; this turns into a negative number.

Consider `CAST`:

```
SELECT CAST(@@global.max_binlog_cache_size AS UNSIGNED)/1024/1024/1024;
       --> 17179869183.999996185303
```